# Upload file to SharePoint online list using angular js

Tags: sharepoint-online, angularjs

I was trying to upload a file using angular js. Here I am adding my code let anyone know what i am doing wrong here.$scope.myfile always coming as undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html ng-app="myApp"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head><body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Title" required>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="description" ng-model="description" placeholder="Description" required>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="file" ng-model="myfile"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Include the AngularJS library and your app script here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.uploadFile = function() {
            var file = $scope.myfile;
            var title = $scope.title;
            var description = $scope.description;
            var uploadUrl = "https://mysite/sites/Classic_Site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ContactDetails')/rootfolder/files/add(url='" + file.name + "',overwrite=true)";
            var digest = document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {
                var buffer = this.result;
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                var content = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray();
                for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                    content.append(bytes[i]);
                }

                $http.post(uploadUrl, content, {
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                        'Content-Length': content.getLength(),
                        'X-File-Name': file.name,
                        'X-File-Title': title,
                        'X-File-Description': description
                    }
                }).then(function(response) {
                    console.log('File uploaded successfully');
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('Error uploading file: ', error);
                });
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: check if this helps: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-multiple-files-to-sharepoint-list-on-single-click-using-angular-and-jquer/. Also, you can add `onchange` event on your input file element and push the selected files in scope variable using JavaScript code.